# python - How do you use the 'test' dataset after cross-validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm newbie with Python, and i need help please.
i applied cross validation on my "Test dataset (60% of my dataset)", and now i'm trying to find how to test my classifier on the rest of my dataset (Test dataset - 40%).
I used the following code:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('NvDataSet.csv', sep=';')
dataset = dataset.dropna()
print(dataset.info())
#dataset = pd.read_csv('Urban1.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,76].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting SVM to the Training set
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#Making the accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

I observed the results before cross validation: "Accuracy: 95,97%", after that i applied the cross validation function on my Test dataset.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies= cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X= X_train, y= y_train, cv= 10)
accuracies.mean()
```

"Cross validation mean Accuracy= 93.58%"

What should i do now to give to my classifier tested with cross validation technique the test dataset : X_test and y_test ?!

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

It gives the same results before cross validation application, Accuracy=95.97% nothing changed ?

Comment: Looks correct actually....are you expecting something else? Could you include the scores for your training and test set? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Doesn't seem to have an issue.

Comment: Thanks u so much sir for answering me, i edited my question .. u can check the scores sir ..

Comment: Firstly this stack overflow is for coding issues. I cannot verify that your scores are good/bad or expected as I have no knowledge of the underlying data set, etc and expected outputs. I can only tell that it looks like you have done each step in the scikit learning process properly and if no errors are being shown it should be fine.

Comment: thank u sir for your answer, but i'm not looking for scores verification.
I'm looking for the function that we use to test my classifier after the cross validation steps with a test dataset, thats all ..
I'm not sure if the right function to use is 
y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test) !!!

Comment: Actually it is. Thats how you test your classifier. It will return the predictions. And you simply check the score by comparing it with the "true values" of y_test that you have which returns you the accuracy.

Comment: thank u sir for your help